# how to upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

A month ago, I had to upgrade from Windows 8 to windows 10 on my PC, Microsoft gave me a month for trial .. after the month expired I can't edit my files on Word, Excel etc ... they're telling to purchase the software which I'm not willing ... I tried to upgrade back to Windows 8 ... but I couldn't .. it seems like they're blocking me from doing so ... is there any other way I can upgrade back to Windows 8?

Comment: The place to ask this would be http://superuser.com I am sure they already have this question actually. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One free option to be able to edit your MS Office files, (Word, Excel, etc.), without reverting to Windows 8 is to install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/).

LibreOffice is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform including Windows
- Can create and edit Word documents in Write
- Can create and edit Excel spreadsheets in Calc
- Can create and edit PowerPoint presentations in Impress
- etc.